# phpmyadmin stuck on processing request

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am new to databases in general so I am probably making a beginners error.

phpmyadmin simply gets stuck on "Processing request" when trying to add columns to a newly generated table of a preexisting database. Also, when trying to create a new table through the "create table" button on the database homepage nothing is created. It only seems to work with the "new" button in the left-hand side menu but then I cannot add columns or save the database.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: I've seen something similar before, it was caused by mod_security on the server. The server admins made a tweak to the rules and then phpMyAdmin worked properly again ..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "Processing Request" hang when trying to make new databases. I updated my PhpMyAdmin version (4.7.7) to the latest one (4.8.3) and this fixed it.